# error occurred when run site

Tags: sql

this error occurred when run site

Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I solved It The Connection string information wasn't right

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create the user and give them permission to your database.

You can do this under Security in SQL Server Management Studio or create a SQL query and paste the following in:

```
USE [DBNAME];
CREATE USER [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE] FOR LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE]
GO
```

You may also need to add them to a role like this:

```
USE [DBNAME];
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'
GO
```